# When running an Async/Await Experiment, operations do not occur in expected order

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I have created an experiment (run in XUnit) to test output. I use three methods - the test method, an asynchronous method that calls await, and an inner Task that sleeps for 5 seconds.

```
    [Fact]
    public void TestAsyncRunning()
    {
        _testOutput.WriteLine("Beginning Test");
        _testOutput.WriteLine("Calling RunningAsync");

        var t = RunningAsync();

        _testOutput.WriteLine("In outer method, after calling async method");

        t.Wait(); //IOW, Thread.Join();

        _testOutput.WriteLine("Exiting Test");
    }


    private async Task RunningAsync()
    {
        _testOutput.WriteLine("RunningAsync: Enter Method");
        _testOutput.WriteLine("RunningAsync: Calling and awaiting inner running");
        await InnerRunning();
        _testOutput.WriteLine("RunningAsync: Returning");   
    }

    private Task InnerRunning()
    {
        _testOutput.WriteLine("InnerRunning: Begin method");
        _testOutput.WriteLine("InnerRunning: Sleeping For 5 seconds");
        var t = Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(5000));
        _testOutput.WriteLine("InnerRunning: Wake up and exit");
        return t;
    }
```

In the following output, the lines with the asterisks is where the unexpected order occurs.

The output I expect is

```
Beginning Test
Calling RunningAsync
RunningAsync: Enter Method
RunningAsync: Calling and awaiting inner running
InnerRunning: Begin method
InnerRunning: Sleeping For 5 seconds
*In outer method, after calling async method
*InnerRunning: Wake up and exit
RunningAsync: Returning
Exiting Test
```

The output I get is

```
Beginning Test
Calling RunningAsync
RunningAsync: Enter Method
RunningAsync: Calling and awaiting inner running
InnerRunning: Begin method
InnerRunning: Sleeping For 5 seconds
*InnerRunning: Wake up and exit
*In outer method, after calling async method
RunningAsync: Returning
Exiting Test
```

It appears that the async method is actually running async but the method it calls is running synchronously. Does this have to do with the TaskScheduler? I am clearly missing something...….

Comment: I figured out my problem. There was concurrency going on but my "WriteLine" comments weren't in the correct places. Here's my full answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60231882/1871495

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found the answer. My problem was I put the Debugger Lines in the wrong place. I change the innermost method to

```
    private Task InnerRunning()
    {

        _testOutput.WriteLine("InnerRunning: Begin method");

        _testOutput.WriteLine("InnerRunning: Starting Task");
        var t = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            _testOutput.WriteLine("InnerRunning Lambda: Sleeping For 5 seconds");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            _testOutput.WriteLine("InnerRunning Lambda: Wake up and exit");
        });
        _testOutput.WriteLine("InnerRunning: After Task");

        return t;
    }
```

And I now get this Output:

```
Beginning Test
Calling RunningAsync
RunningAsync: Enter Method
RunningAsync: Calling and awaiting inner running
InnerRunning: Begin method
InnerRunning: Starting Task
InnerRunning: After Task
InnerRunning Lambda: Sleeping For 5 seconds
In outer method, after calling async method
InnerRunning Lambda: Wake up and exit
RunningAsync: Returning
Exiting Test
```

Thank you everyone for your thought-provoking comments!

Answer (score 3):

`InnerRunning` is not asynchronous. It's a synchronous method that returns a `Task`. So these messages will always appear together:

```
InnerRunning: Begin method
InnerRunning: Sleeping For 5 seconds
InnerRunning: Wake up and exit
```

If you want `InnerRunning` to asynchronously wait for the `Task.Run` delegate, then you need to `await` that task in that method:

```
_testOutput.WriteLine("InnerRunning: Begin method");
_testOutput.WriteLine("InnerRunning: Sleeping For 5 seconds");
await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(5000));
_testOutput.WriteLine("InnerRunning: Wake up and exit");
```

For more introductory information around `async`/`await`, I recommend my [`async` intro](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

Comment: *It's a synchronous method that returns a Task.* This sentence confuses me. My understanding is that every method that returns an incomplete `Task` is always asynchronous.

Comment: Even, I was thinking so but it will be executed synchronously because you are not using await keyword

Comment: Stephen! You're the man! I've read your blog on async/await many, many times and each time I understand it a bit more. I recommend you to all my colleagues all the time. 

I now see that innerRunning is running synchronously... (is it? Why doesn't Task.Run work here)? I am trying to manually simulate an asynchronous method. Obviously, my method is a "Delegate" Task and not a "Promise" Task, but I want to fudge it myself. Do I need to use APM to do so? 

The reason I am experimenting is I want to be a concurrency wizard (like yourself), and I want to do the "under the hood" stuff myself.

Comment: `Task.Run` executes its delegate on a thread pool thread. If you want to simulate an asynchronous method by running synchronous work on the thread pool, just use `Task.Run`. If you want to simulate a true asynchronous method, use `TaskCompletionSource<T>`.

Comment: @StephenCleary Hmmmm. I've tried Task.CompletedTask (which I understand does the same thing as tcs.SetResult(someBSValue)) without using Task.Run and wasn't getting a better result. Does tcs actually work here?

Thanks again.

Comment: @Moe45673: TCS works if you have something actually asynchronous. If you have synchronous code that you want to treat asynchronously, `Task.Run` is the correct tool.

Answer (score 0):

**Adding more to Athanasios Kataras & Stephen Cleary post's**

You can even see the change in thread for incoming and returning thread ids and this code will qualify for full asynchronous code. if you use t.Wait() it just makes just immediate async methods to run synchronously :

```
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Beginning Test");
        Console.WriteLine("Calling RunningAsync");
        Console.WriteLine("1 " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        await RunningAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("2 " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Console.WriteLine("In outer method, after calling async method");
        Console.WriteLine("Exiting Test");
    }


    private static async Task RunningAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("RunningAsync: Enter Method");
        Console.WriteLine("RunningAsync: Calling and awaiting inner running");
        Console.WriteLine("3 " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        await InnerRunning();
        Console.WriteLine("4 " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Console.WriteLine("RunningAsync: Returning");
    }

    private static async Task InnerRunning()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("InnerRunning: Begin method");
        Console.WriteLine("InnerRunning: Sleeping For 5 seconds");
        Console.WriteLine("5 " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(5000));
        Console.WriteLine("6 " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Console.WriteLine("InnerRunning: Wake up and exit");
    }
```

Output will be :

```
Calling RunningAsync
1 1
RunningAsync: Enter Method
RunningAsync: Calling and awaiting inner running
3 1
InnerRunning: Begin method
InnerRunning: Sleeping For 5 seconds
5 1
6 4
InnerRunning: Wake up and exit
4 4
RunningAsync: Returning
2 4
In outer method, after calling async method
Exiting Test
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your code like this:

```
var t = await RunningAsync();

_testOutput.WriteLine("In outer method, after calling async method");
```

When you are not awaiting an async method, the outer one will continue running, especially when the inner one is waiting.

Adding the await there will fix the issue.

Comment: This does not address my issue, this makes the code run synchronously within its scope.

I thank you for taking the time to address this, though!